# Approximating a "Not Connected" pin on an IC with a high value resistor

Tags: analog, resistance

I'm looking at using this[0] chip as a difference amp.  However, I would like to be able to change the gain electronically.

For this chip, the gain is set by either leaving unconnected, or grounding, or connecting to the input, some combination of the +/-REFA, +/-REFB, +/-REFC pins.  so, for example, for a gain of 10, the input is connected to +/-REFA, and all the others are left "not connected"

The way that I was thinking about simulating this is using a MOSFET to switch the pin onto a very high value (100M or so) resistor to ground.  If I consider an unconnected pin as basically having a very (very very) low current path to ground, through some unknown resistor (the air, the board itself, etc.), then a high value resistor should behave like leaving that pin disconnected.

Is this an appropriate way to do this?  Is there a standard way to approximate "non-connected" pins?

[0] http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6375fa.pdf

Comment: What's wrong with just leaving it open?

Comment: Because I would like to switch from gain of 1 to gain of 10.

Comment: He's asking what's wrong with leaving the OFF pins open. We understand that you want to switch them but don't understand why you want to add in high value resistances.

Comment: I must not have been thinking about the off state of the FET.  That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The LT6375.*

> The way that I was thinking about simulating this is using a MOSFET to switch the pin onto a very high value (100M or so) resistor to ground.

Why bother? - just leave your MOSFET switch at high impedance. There's no need to add in a high value resistance.

Your problem will be what type of MOSFET switch to use. When open-circuit they will have an alternating voltage on them and this will alternate above and below zero volts as the LT device uses a symmetrical supply. (See marked points on Figure 1.) If your switch doesn't block symmetrically when off and doesn't conduct symmetrically when on you will introduce distortion.

You will have to research dual-rail CMOS analog switches, I suspect. I'm only familiar with the CD4016-style analog switches but they only run on single power rails.

Comment: The CD4051 will work with +/- 7.5 volts supplies but the ON resistance is 120 ohms. May or may not be a factor here. Option to use tiny Aromat DPDT relay...

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but the logic gets messy. It would be handy if it would accept 5 V logic to switch the analogs. 120R would probably be fine here.

Comment: The logic section of the CD4051 is CMOS 2v to 5v, and has its own gnd pin.

Comment: The latest version, still in production: http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf

Comment: Interesting. I don't remember that chip from the days of my youth. Was it part of the original CD4xxx range? Bedtime here. I'll read it tomorrow.

Comment: As a starting point re: dual-rail switches, I'd look at the [LTC222](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC222)...

Comment: It is an improved version made by TI, but other make similar copies. 40 years later and it is still a popular IC. Much-much cheaper than Analog Devices muxes.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into the CD4053B, and other analog multiplexers, they look like exactly what I need.